# python write to file from dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new with Python and I know that piece of code is very simple and lacks some statements, actually I need to write to file from dictionary. This code runs but only writes the last item in dict to the file which is `"heba6677..."` . Thanks for your help.

```
ab={'engy':'011199887765',
    'wafa2':'87878857578',
    'heba':'6677553636'}
for name, mobile in ab.items():
    print ('Contact %s at %s' % (name, mobile))
    f=open('D:\glo.txt','w')
    f.write(name)
    f.write(mobile)
f.close()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to keep adding lines to your file, open it with the `a` mode, as described in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#open):

```
for (name, mobile) in ab.iteritems():
    with open(...., "a") as f:
        print ('Contact %s at %s' % (name, mobile))
        f.write(name)
        f.write(mobile)
```

Using `w` as mode means `writing`: your file will be overwritten.

Answer (score 2):

Each time you open the file in `w` mode, its previous content is erased. So you only should do it once, before the loop. Best of all, do it with a `with` statement:

```
ab={'engy':'011199887765',
    'wafa2':'87878857578',
    'heba':'6677553636'}
with open('D:\glo.txt','w') as f:
    for name, mobile in ab.items():
        print ('Contact %s at %s' % (name, mobile))
        f.write(name)
        f.write(mobile)
```