# python print to file prints correctly in console but not in file

Tags: python, dictionary, io

Being new to python unfortunately I get stuck on rather trivial things.
I am trying to print a dictionary to file.
Dict entries look like:

```
{'a': array(['a', 'b', 'c', '123.d', 'lalal.fufu'], dtype=object)}
```

I am using [python write to file from dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12599033/python-write-to-file-from-dictionary) answer to do the printing, as

```
for (name, mobile) in Dict.iteritems():
    with open('C:\dir\file.csv', "a") as f:
        print ('A %s gives B %s \n' % (name, str(mobile)))
        f.write(name)
        f.write(mobile)
f.close()
```

but for some reason i get the output in console window (correctly) but the file contains gibberish in the mobile part. It's like the mobile is not converted to string despite casting of str(). Haven't found any similar case in answered questions :=(

Help please?

Thanks!

Comment: Out of curiosity: why are you using `array.array` if all you are storing is objects? Why not use a regular Python list instead?

Comment: open your file first and then loop, you are reopening the file every time though the for loop which is unnecessary

Comment: Martijn - the items come from diff arrays which i store in order to use later on in a single data-structure. Dict was chosen as it seemed the easiest to use. If you have any other suggestions, i am more than open to hear these.

Comment: Padraic - can you please elaborate on how the code should look like? Something like this? open('C:\dir\file.csv', "a") as f for (name, mobile) in Dict.iteritems():
        print ('A %s gives B %s \n' % (name, str(mobile)))
        f.write(name)
        f.write(mobile)
f.close() Thanks!

Comment: yes obviously using `with`, just open the file first then loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did cast your object to a string in the console line:

```
print ('A %s gives B %s \n' % (name, str(mobile)))
```

But you forgot to do it in the `f.write` method:

```
f.write(mobile)
```

It should be:

```
f.write(str(mobile))
```