# How do I convert the user's input into a file name?

Tags: python

```
name = input("What's your name? (first, last)")
nameparts = name.split()
firstName = nameparts[]
lastName = nameparts[]
fileName = lastName+"."+firstName
```

Above is the code that I have at the moment where I take the user's input and separate the first and last name, but after that it gets fuzzy. I can't remember the operation that needs to be implemented to make a file out of the first and last name.

User's input:

```
john doe
```

Desired output:

`john.doe`

Maybe this will help better--I'm basically making a file out of the first and last name so I can have a user database for every person that'll input their first and last name. I already have the code to read and write into it I just don't know how to convert the input into a file for the information to go into.

Comment: After you take the input, use this code `filename = (".").join(name.split())`

Comment: [Python Write To File From Dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12599109/2359945) has as short example showing how to open a file in `w` mode and write to it.

Comment: Replace your file open filename with a variable. The filename may be a string in quotes. Replace that string with the variable. The variable should be concat of first+.+last.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'm assuming that you were trying to save the name of this person to a file, while incorporating their names into the filename. Well you got the first parts right.

```
name = input("What's your name? (first, last)")
nameparts = name.split()
firstName = nameparts[0] 
lastName = nameparts[1]

# for filename, we can choose any format to arrange it in, use - to represent a space.

 filename = firstName + "-" + lastName + ".txt" # don't forget to add a file \extention to the end of your file in this case, its a text file.
```

Then to write to the file:

```
with open(filename, "+w") as fout: # The '+w' indicates that you will be appending to the file. 'w' means you will overwrite it
     fout.write(firstName + " " + lastName)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah the code is good just needs the indexing in the nameparts array

```
name = input("What's your name? (first, last)")
nameparts = name.split()
firstName = nameparts[0]
lastName = nameparts[1]
fileName = lastName+"."+firstName
```

You could also replace the space with dot

```
name = input("What's your name? (first, last)")
fileName = name.replace(' ', '.')
```

Comment: That's great to hear, and thanks for the simplicity tip. Also, because I'll have multiple name file I'll assume I shouldn't open it as file = open('fileName','w') in order to write to it. Do you know how I should format it to open?

Comment: Sorry about that, was a little busy but yeah what @CobraPi said would work absolutely great

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
name = input("What's your name? (first, last)").replace(' ', '.')
```

**User's input:**

```
john doe
```

**name will store:**

```
john.doe
```